# Excluding an entire address block of IPs in a Google search or group of domains

Tags: google-search

How does one exclude an entire address block of IPs in a Google search or group of domains, because searching Google for real help with the -superuser.com still doesn't stop the results from being polluted with unwanted sites.

Comment: Did you try <search terms> site:superuser.com? And what about SU's own search?

Comment: Are you trying to block all results from superuser.com, or only see results from superuser.com?

Answer (score 1):

To exclusively search a given site use `search term site:abc.com`

To exclude a site use `search term -site:abc.com`